# Why doesn't iMacros script work on all browser?

Tags: firefox, browser, profile, imacros

I've created around 5 iMacros, they we're all working properly, after i tried to use them in a new firefox profile, it didn't work, but in my default browser, it is still working like a charm, i needed to create a new imacro for the new profile, and tried to use them on the default browser, but the new one didn't work on the default browser too!
What am i missing, what is the problem? 
p.s. none of the two macros worked on an other computer, and no i didn't use XY coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Open those macros with Notepad (the default Windows Notepad). Try to save as and select encoding UTF8. Then try to run macros again.

Comment: Possible with Notepad++ ?

Comment: Edit: Nope, didn't work either... To make it run on several pc, i always need to create a new profile for firefox, and there is one working, but the other one isn't

Comment: Use the default profile on FireFox. This is first time to see this error. Is there a screenshot of this error?